# How to comma-separate a set of strings without the final comma

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
int rowPosition = 0;
string WorkerName = "";
DataTable dtAllotedManpower = new DataTable();
dtAllotedManpower.Columns.Add("WorkerName");
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewTotalManpower.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow drAllotedManpower = dtAllotedManpower.NewRow();
        CheckBox chkChild = (CheckBox)GridViewTotalManpower.Rows[rowPosition].FindControl("chkChild");
        if (chkChild.Checked == true)
        {
            WorkerName = Convert.ToString(GridViewTotalManpower.DataKeys[rowPosition]["WorkerName"].ToString()) + "," + WorkerName;

        }
        rowPosition++;
    }
    hidfWorker.Value = WorkerName;
```

I have Written the following piece of code. My hidden field values are coming like this

"HARSH,RIMA,"

But i want the value "HARSH,RIMA" (without ',' after the last word). how to construct the code for that ? . there will be no 'comma' after last word .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add them to a collection then use `string.Join`:

```
var list = new List<string>();

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewTotalManpower.Rows) {
    // ...other code here...
    list.Add(Convert.ToString(GridViewTotalManpower.DataKeys[rowPosition]["WorkerName"].ToString()));
}

 hidfWorker.Value = string.Join(", ", list);
```

Comment: this is the best way to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string.TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
hidfWorker.Value = WorkerName.TrimEnd(',');
```

This will remove the last comma from the string.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Indeed. You do have the proper solution :-)

Comment: Santanu also refer the answer by @Simon

Answer (score 1):

you can use the substring method

```
hidfWorker.Value=WorkerName.Substring(0,WorkerName.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder instead of string if you are frequently changing the string like in loops, because when you use string it will create new string object every time you changes it,

```
StringBuilder workerName = new StringBuilder();
```

And in your loop

```
workerName.Append(Convert.ToString(GridViewTotalManpower.DataKeys[rowPosition]["WorkerName"].ToString()) + ",");
```

Then trim last ',' character using TrimEnd method

```
hidfWorker.Value = workerName.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Hope this helps.